# Is it possible to collect response data (body) from an API requests in azure?

Tags: azure, api, containers, httpresponse, monitor

I am hosting models on azure and I would like to collect responses (body) from our API calls. So far I am able to collect the API requests data, but I would also like to collect the response which is sent to the 'client'. How can I do this in Azure?

We tried several things (monitoring --> logs but they do only collect the requests and response signal (`200`, `400` or `500`), but somehow nothing is logging our response body.

Do I have to configure this somehow coding?

e.g. `request: location_from = 'ab', location_to = 'ba', material = 'sand' 
     response: predictive_duration = 10,5 hours`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve that. You can:

1-Use an AOP framework and log before (received parameters) and after (response) from your APIs.

1.1-You can achieve the same thing using the Decorator design pattern

2-You can implement ITelemetryInitializer + Application Insights to log response code / response body from your apis:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#add-properties-itelemetryinitializer